# How to Change Nameservers for Ghost Blog without Nuking Site

Tags: apache

I've not gotten a definitive answer to this question from host or registrar, and hope I can explain it well enough here.

I have a domain registered with InternetBS.net and hosted through Site 5. It uses Site 5 nameservers.

I want to install a Ghost blog at blog.mysite.com. To do so, I need to add a CNAME record to the domain through InternetBS, redirecting blog.themeparkpress.com to my new Ghost blog.

So far, so good.

But when I do that, the nameservers will change automatically from those provided by Site 5 to those used by InternetBS.

I'm concerned that this change will make my site inaccessible (except for the lonely Ghost blog). Am I going about this in the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the name servers that belong to your domain registrar to make adjustments to the DNS information. You may want to check to see what, if any, additional information is in your domain records hosted by Site 5.